# Google Earth Enterprise vs. ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, google, google-earth-enterprise

All - looks like it's been a while (May '11) since the [GEE vs. ArcGIS server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-google-earth-enterprise-compare-to-arcgis-server-and-geoserver) has been updated. Would anyone have more current feedback on this?  Is the price for GEE still hovering around $620K USD?

Comment: Are you referring to an existing comparison? If so, are you able to include a link to that page, please?

Comment: Here you go -http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-google-earth-enterprise-compare-to-arcgis-server-and-geoserver

Comment: I'm thinking that this is better treated as a Duplicate of the original question that can be edited and/or have additional answers and comments added to it.